# ALTER a replicated column in SQL Server 2008 R2. Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

I want to alter columns in `StudentPerformance` table

Columns to be altered are -

```
StudentName varchar(50) to StudentName varchar(100)
Percentage decimal(18,0) to Percentage decimal(18,2)
```

It is configured for merge replication.

- Will it make my current snapshot obselete?
- Will I have to re-initialze all the subscriptions?
- Will it update all the records in the table and it will increase traffic in replication when I run the alter statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to do this using *ALTER TABLE  ALTER COLUMN*  syntax at the Publisher.  By default the schema changes will be propagated on the next synchronization, publication property **@replicate_ddl** must be set to true.  No new snapshot or reinitialization required in most cases.

For example, I can change my SalesLT.Customer Title column from nvarchar(8) null to nvarchar(10) null by executing on the publication database:

```
ALTER TABLE SalesLT.Customer ALTER COLUMN Title NVARCHAR(10) NULL
```

In most cases the schema change will replicate out on the next sync, there are some exceptions that are covered in [Making Schema Changes on Publication Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx).

Comment: any idea if it will all the rows will be updated and synchronized (uploaded/downloaded) across all servers in replication?

Comment: Yes, as long as the schema change is not made on a column involved in a join or parameterized filter.

Comment: i altered the columns and it didnt make my snapshot obselete :) neither did it update all the rows to affect replication speed :)